# Is there a way to get worksheetfunction.randbetween to work for a time range?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to coding and just want to thank everyone on this site who has already helped me so much.

I'm trying to build a random time generator that will generate a random time within a range specified by the user.  I am currently using the WorksheetFunction.Randbetween command which effectively generates a random time, however it is not within the specified range.  This code is part of a larger userform which does similar functions.  The rest of the code works fine(ish).

My question:  What do I need to add to my line of code to get it to effectively generate time within the specified range?  I also need to make sure it works off of 24h "HH:MM:SS" or "HH:MM" format.

I've tried using Round and WorksheetFunction.Randbetween

```
Private Sub Generate_Data_Button_Click()

Dim emptyRow As Long

Randomize 

'Make Data Active
Sheet1.Activate

'Determine emptyRow
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))+1

'Transfer information to template
Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = WorksheetFunction.Randbetween (start_time_textbox.value, end_time_textbox.value) + Rnd()

'Format cell on template
Cells(emptyRow, 4).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"

End Sub
```

Comment: `RANDBETWEEN` returns an integer number. 24 hours is equivalent to 1, so by definition there's no random integer between your start time and end time - both are between 0 and 1. You could multiply each by 86400 to get the corresponding time in seconds, use the seconds in `RANDBETWEEN`, and then divide the result by 86400 to get a time.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for replying.  That makes sense.  I am still getting hung up on how it is generating a random time but not inside the range I provided.  For example if I input 08:00 as the start time and 10:00 as the end time, it will output everything from 02:30 up to 23:59.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Randomize/Rnd method**

After `Randomize`, `Rnd` generates a pseudo-random decimal number between zero and one each time it is called. If your times are full time values (e.g. 23:59:45) then convert the strings returned by the input boxes using the TimeValue string-to-double conversion and use some math to force the Rnd value(s) inside the start and stop times.

```
Private Sub Generate_Data_Button_Click()

    Dim emptyRow As Long, tstart As Double, tend As Double

    'convert string times from input to true time as double
    tstart = TimeValue(start_time_textbox.Value)
    tend = TimeValue(end_time_textbox.Value)

    Randomize

    'Make Data Active
    With Worksheets("Data")

        'Determine emptyRow in COLUMN D
        emptyRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1

        'Transfer information to template
        .Cells(emptyRow, "D").Value = (tend - tstart) * Rnd() + tstart

        'Format cell on template
        .Cells(emptyRow, "D").NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"

    End With

End Sub
```

**RandBetween method**

To use the worksheet's Randbetween function you need to convert the start time and end times to long integers representing the number of seconds since midnight then randomize between them. Take the result and convert it back to a time value by diving by the number of seconds in a day.

```
Private Sub Generate_Data_Button_Click2()

    Dim emptyRow As Long, tstart As Long, tend As Long, siad As Long

    siad = 86400 'seconds in a day

    'convert string times from input to seconds in a day as Long Integer
    tstart = TimeValue(start_time_textbox.Value)  * siad
    tend = TimeValue(end_time_textbox.Value)  * siad


    'Make Data Active
    With Worksheets("Data")

        'Determine emptyRow in COLUMN D
        emptyRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1

        'Transfer information to template
        .Cells(emptyRow, "D").Value = Application.RandBetween(tstart, tend) / siad

        'Format cell on template
        .Cells(emptyRow, "D").NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"

    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you again to everyone who helped solve this problem for me.  I've been at this for less than a week so it was definitely a huge help!  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as a UDF. The idea is to generate a random minute to offset from Time1.

First convert the hours and minutes of both times into minutes as the unit.
Then base on the minutes difference, generate a random minutes using the `RandBetween`, deduct the base time, then add this random minutes to the base time (in terms of minutes).

```
Function RandomTimeBetween(FromTime As Range, ToTime As Range) As Date
    Dim Time1 As Date, Time2 As Date, Minutes As Integer
    Time1 = CDate(FromTime.Value)
    Time2 = CDate(ToTime.Value)
    Minutes = Hour(Time1) * 60 + Minute(Time1) ' Base time in minutes
    ' Find the random offset time between them, deduct the base time
    Minutes = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(Minutes, Hour(Time2) * 60 + Minute(Time2)) - Minutes
    RandomTimeBetween = Time1 + TimeSerial(0, Minutes, 0)
End Function
```

If you desire to randomise to the seconds, you need to change to below as overflow can occur at TimeSerial:

```
Function RandomTimeBetween(FromTime As Range, ToTime As Range) As Date
    Dim Time1 As Date, Time2 As Date, Seconds As Long
    Time1 = CDate(FromTime.Value)
    Time2 = CDate(ToTime.Value)
    Seconds = Hour(Time1) * 3600 + Minute(Time1) * 60 + Second(Time1) ' Base time in seconds
    ' Find the random offset time between them, deduct the base time
    Seconds = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(Seconds, Hour(Time2) * 3600 + Minute(Time2) * 60 + Second(Time2)) - Seconds
    RandomTimeBetween = Time1 + TimeSerial(Seconds \ 3600, Seconds \ 60, Seconds Mod 60)
End Function
```